# How do I set up an authenticated JavaMailSender in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, jakarta-mail

I seem to be unable to properly configure Spring's JavaMailSender implementation via Spring Boot's `application.properties`.

The following code using standard JavaMail API sends email messages just fine:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
    }
});

try {

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@gmail.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("recipientaddress@gmail.com"));
    message.setSubject("Test Message");
    message.setText("This is a test message.");

    Transport.send(message);
    System.out.println("Sent");
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

My Spring Boot application's `application.properties` contains the following properties relevant to email delivery:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.username=username
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=3000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

The following code in the Spring Boot application is not sending any email, but it is also not throwing any exception:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender emailSender;

@RequestMapping("/sendEmail")
public ResponseEntity<Void> sendEmail(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

    try {

        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
        helper.setFrom("sender@gmail.com");
        helper.setTo("recipientaddress@gmail.com");
        helper.setText("This is a test message.");
        helper.setSubject("Test Message");
        emailSender.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent");
    }
    catch (MessagingException me) {
        logger.error("Failed to send email: {}", me.getMessage());
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Show us some logs just to be sure you are not getting any errors. Also,         change System.out.println("Sent"); to logger.info or something so everything is captured in single log file.

Comment: Apparently had something to do with the connection over the work/office network. It appears to be working now. I will update my question and possibly clarify with just the set properties that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you used standard JavaMail APIs, you performed the authentication with

```
new PasswordAuthentication ("username", "password");
```

With Spring boot you did not authenticate, you have two options:

1. Authenticate using user and password from application.properties, create session like to that used with JavaMail API
2. Delegate authentication for Spring Boot, remove all settings related to email config from the application.properties and use defined on the server, replace with

> spring.mail.jndi-name=java:jboss/mail/exampleJboss

the sendEmail method will work with JavaMailSender